# OOP - Unbound value when attempting to call a class in Reason

Tags: oop, ocaml, reason

I have the following class, which has a method, methodA, I am trying to call (using Reason):

```
class abstractProductA = {
  as self;
  pub methodA => "name";
};

abstractProductA#methodA;
```

The compiler outputs the following error:

```
Unbound value abstractProductA
```

Any suggestions would be more than welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an instance of the class:

```
(new abstractProductA)#methodA;
```